# render one photo from mobile while it is rendered 4 photos on web Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, rendering

There are four images rendered from an API in the web browser.
I want to render only one photo while opening it from mobile,
what are the possible ways to achieve this?

The data fetched all the images together.

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="
      fusion-fullwidth
      fullwidth-box
      fusion-builder-row-6
      hundred-percent-fullwidth
      non-hundred-percent-height-scrolling
      fusion-equal-height-columns
    "
    style="
      background-color: #3e3731;
      background-position: left top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      border-color: #eae9e9;
      border-style: solid;
    "
  >
    <div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-row">
      <div
        v-for="(collection, index) in box_collections"
        :key="collection.bo_id"
        :class="
          'fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion-builder-column-' +
          (index + 11) +
          ' fusion_builder_column_1_4 1_4 fusion-one-fourth fusion-no-small-visibility'
        "
        style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px"
      >
        <div
          class="fusion-column-wrapper fusion-flex-column-wrapper-legacy"
          :style="
            'background-image: url(\'' +
            collection.bo_url +
            '\'); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; padding: 0px; min-height: 252px; height: auto;'
          "
          :data-bg-url="collection.bo_url"
        >
          <div
            class="fusion-column-content-centered"
            style="min-height: 252px; height: auto"
          >
            <div class="fusion-column-content">
              <div class="fusion-sep-clear" />
              <div
                class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep"
                style="
                  margin-left: auto;
                  margin-right: auto;
                  margin-top: 250px;
                  width: 100%;
                "
              />
              <div class="fusion-sep-clear" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="fusion-clearfix" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Shall I refetch them? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Lazy load if you need to support modern (evergreen) browsers.

Comment: It will avoid the need to load it initially. Otherwise, using IntersectionObserver's API is also a viable solution to have it working fine if you need to homemade it.

Comment: how the code should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would achieve this kind of feature.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>all the interesting images: {{ pokemon.sprites.other }}</pre>
    <div class="reference-breakpoint"></div>

    <p>Down below are all the remaining images ⬇️</p>
    <img :src="pokemon.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default" />
    <img
      class="hide-when-mobile"
      loading="lazy"
      :src="pokemon.sprites.other.home.front_default"
    />
    <img
      class="hide-when-mobile"
      loading="lazy"
      :src="pokemon.sprites.other.home.front_shiny"
    />
    <img
      class="hide-when-mobile"
      loading="lazy"
      :src="pokemon.sprites.other['official-artwork'].front_default"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const pokemon = await $axios.$get(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard'
    )
    return { pokemon }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
img {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
.reference-breakpoint {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .hide-when-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```